# Нужно ли ставить тире в преложении?

Tags: тире

> На улице было тепло, падал снег, все вокруг белое-белое.

После слова "вокруг" нужно ставить тире, т.к. пропущено слово "было" или можно без тире?

Answer (score 1):

*На улице было тепло, падал снег, **все вокруг белое-блое**.*

Тире здесь не ставится. В предложении (3) пропущена связка "быть", так как использована форма настоящего времени.

Именная часть сказуемого выражена **прилагательным**. В таких случаях возможно только **интонационное** тире, но для го постановки нет причин (паузы нет, ударение падает на сказуемое)

Это авторское решение, так как в двух предыдущих предложениях сказуемое стоит в форме прошедшего времени.